# If an app has multiple models with the same field, whats the best practice for keeping things DRY?

Tags: django, django-models

For example, if I have 3 models that look like this:

```
class CallLog(models.Model):
    lead_id = models.BigIntegerField("Lead ID")
    #  other fields


class EmailLog(models.Model):
    lead_id = models.BigIntegerField("Lead ID")
    #  other fields


class TextLog(models.Model):
    lead_id = models.BigIntegerField("Lead ID")
    #  other fields
```

Do I add `lead_id` to each model individually or is there a way to only type it once?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can define an [*abstract base class* <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes):

```
class LeadId(models.Model):
    lead_id = models.BigIntegerField("Lead ID")

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

and then inherit this in the other models:

```
class CallLog(LeadId, models.Model):
    # other fields…


class EmailLog(LeadId, models.Model):
    # other fields…


class TextLog(LeadId, models.Model):
    # other fields…
```

You can define multiple such abstract base classes, and use multiple inheritance such that models inherit from multiple of such classes.

Comment: is there any practical benefit here? it looks too over-engineered. In this way, you will have excessive table `LeadIdModel`, and you still will have `lead_id` field in each other models

Comment: @oruchkin: no, an *abstract base class* does *not* construct a table, this is only used to define logic, and then let the inherited models add these fields to these tables, there is thus *no* `LeadIdModel` table.

Comment: Is there any reason to inherit subclasses from both `LeadIdModel` and `models.Model`?

Comment: @SUTerliakov: no, inheriting from `LeadIdModel` is sufficient, but personally I also inherit from `Model` to make it clear that it is a model, especially if multiple abstract base classes are used.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Sir willem, model doesn't require model to be the suffix, it will be better if it is named only `LeadId` instead of `LeadIDModel`.